# Line 22:6: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'auth.token'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I don't know why this error came, the only thing I know is that the error is from private.js. In the website all the things are working properly but this error is showing in the console

> ./src/components/Layout/Routes/adminRoute.js   Line 22:6:  React Hook
> useEffect has a missing dependency: 'auth.token'. Either include it or
> remove the dependency array
>
> Line 22:7:  React Hook useEffect has a complex expression in the dependency array. Extract it to a separate
> variable so it can be statically checked

private.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useAuth } from "../../../context/auth";
import React from "react";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import Spinner from "../../spinner";

export default function PrivateRoute() {
  const [ok, setOk] = useState(false);
  const [auth] = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    const authCheck = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("/api/v1/auth/user-auth");
      if (res.data.ok) {
        setOk(true);
      } else {
        setOk(false);
      }
    };
    if (auth?.token) authCheck();
  }, [auth?.token]);

  return ok ? <Outlet /> : <Spinner />;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The second error makes the issue clear: The linter can't reliably figure out what `auth?.token` means, and it's suggested you move that to a "separate variable" instead, like this:

```
const token = auth?.token;  // <======
useEffect(() => {
  const authCheck = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("/api/v1/auth/user-auth");
    if (res.data.ok) {
      setOk(true);
    } else {
      setOk(false);
    }
  };
  if (token) authCheck();   // <======
}, [token]);                // <======
```

*(I was surprised `authCheck` doesn't seem to use the token anywhere, but if it does in the real code, be sure to change `auth?.token` to `token` there as well.)*

---

Side note: If your `authCheck` function throws an error, nothing will handle it and you'll get an "unhandled rejection" error in the console. That's mostly harmless in browsers, but in general it's best to catch and handle/report errors. You can also just use `res.data.ok` directly when calling `setOk` rather than using an `if`/`else`. For example:

```
const token = auth?.token;
useEffect(() => {
    if (token) {
        const authCheck = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await axios.get("/api/v1/auth/user-auth");
                setOk(res.data.ok)
            } catch (error) {
                // ...handle/report error...
            }
        };
        authCheck();
    }
}, [token]);
```

This may be a place where using the promise methods directly is simpler:

```
const token = auth?.token;
useEffect(() => {
    if (token) {
        axios.get("/api/v1/auth/user-auth")
        .then((res) => setOk(res.data.ok))
        .catch((error) => {
            // ...handle/reprot the error...
        });
    }
}, [token]);
```